# Constructing a triagular DAG

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

Inspired by Project Euler problem 67 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=67) I would like to construct a directed acyclic graph of the data.  I have already solved the problem using a 2D array, but am curious as to an algorithm that would build a DAG from the input text.

It seems very similar to a binary tree except that nodes can share children. I had thought of inserting nodes by using a BFS and inserting the node in both of the first two open spots, but this won't work for the edges of the triangle.

Here is a simple visualization of the DAG I would like to build, with all edges directed downward. The numbers showing the order in which the values are read from the file.

```
                             1
                            / \
                           2   3
                          / \ / \
                         4   5   6
```

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a DAG:

```
public class Problem067 {

    private static BinaryTreeNode<Long> root = null;
    private static LinkedList<LinkedList<BinaryTreeNode<Long>>> data = new LinkedList<LinkedList<BinaryTreeNode<Long>>>();

    private static void readFile() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "inputs//Problem067.txt"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                LinkedList<BinaryTreeNode<Long>> list = new LinkedList<BinaryTreeNode<Long>>();
                for (String num : str.split(" ")) {
                    list.add(new BinaryTreeNode<Long>(Long.parseLong(num)));
                }
                data.add(list);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void buildTree() {
        root = data.get(0).get(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.get(i).size(); j++) {
                data.get(i).get(j).setLeft(data.get(i + 1).get(j));
                data.get(i).get(j).setRight(data.get(i + 1).get(j + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void findMaxRoute(BinaryTreeNode<Long> node) {
        node.setVisited(true);

        if (node.getLeft() == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!node.getLeft().getVisited()) {
            findMaxRoute(node.getLeft());
        }

        if (!node.getRight().getVisited()) {
            findMaxRoute(node.getRight());
        }

        node.setValue(node.getValue()
                + Math.max(node.getLeft().getValue(), node.getRight()
                        .getValue()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFile();
        buildTree();
        findMaxRoute(root);
        System.out.println(root.getValue());
    }
}
```

And here is the tree node:

```
    public class BinaryTreeNode<T> {
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> father = null;
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> left = null;
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> right = null;
    private T value = null;
    private Boolean visited = false;

    public BinaryTreeNode(T val) {
        value = val;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode<T> left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(BinaryTreeNode<T> right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getFather() {
        return father;
    }

    public Boolean getVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    public void setVisited(Boolean visited) {
        this.visited = visited;
    }

}
```